# Using tf.tile to replicate a tensor N times

Tags: tensorflow

My current tensor has shape of (3, 2), e.g.,

`[[ 1.  2.]
 [ 2.  1.]
 [-2. -1.]]`

I would like to expand to a shape of (1, 3, 2) with each second dimension a replica of the entire tensor, e.g.,

```
[[[ 1.  2.]
  [ 2.  1.]
  [ -2.  -1.]]
 [[ 1.  2.]
  [ 2.  1.]
  [ -2.  -1.]]
[[ 1.  2.]
  [ 2.  1.]
  [ -2. -1.]]]
```

I tried the folllowing code but it only replicate each row instead.

```
tiled_vecs = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(input_vecs, 1), [1, 3, 1])
```

Results in

```
[[[ 1.  2.]
[ 1.  2.]
[ 1.  2.]]
[[ 2.  1.]
 [ 2.  1.]
 [ 2.  1.]]
[[-2. -1.]
 [-2. -1.]
 [-2. -1.]]]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work,

> tf.ones([tf.shape(A)[0], 1, 1]) * A

```
# Achieved by creating a 3d matrix as shown below 
# and multiplying it with A, which is `broadcast` to obtain the desired result.
 [[[1.]],
  [[1.]],   * A
  [[1.]]]
```

Code Sample:

```
 #input 
 A = tf.constant([[ 1.,  2.], [ 2. , 1.],[-2., -1.]])
 B = tf.ones([tf.shape(A)[0], 1, 1]) * A

 #output
 array([[[ 1.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  1.],
    [-2., -1.]],

   [[ 1.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  1.],
    [-2., -1.]],

   [[ 1.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  1.],
    [-2., -1.]]], dtype=float32)
```

Also using `tf.tile`, we can obtain the same:

> tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(A,0), [tf.shape(A)[0], 1, 1])

Comment: saved my butt! thanks a lot. I was using `tf.tile` and `tf.fill` but gave me error as the shape was unknown at build time. `tf.ones` saved me.

Comment: In the first example, `tf.expand_dims(tf.ones([tf.shape(A)[0], 1]), 1)`, why use the `expand_dims` on a `ones` Tensor when we can just call `tf.ones([tf.shape(A)[0], 1, 1])`?

Comment: @protagonist, thanks, made the changes in my answer.